# How to use bcrypt with php for password authentication?

Tags: php, bcrypt

I tried the top solution post from [How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php) 
but can't seem to get an example working. I copied the Bcrypt class and added the following code at the bottom of it.

```
$bcrypt = new Bcrypt(15);

// pw on server. Used $pwHash = $bcrypt->hash($formPassword); to get the hash from 'qwerty'.
$serverPw = '$2a$15$Ty6hIEEWFpUFHoKujvdmw.9kmyrwYip2s8TLdjDfNoVJuQx/TGgwu'; 

// user enters plain text pw...
$passAttempt = 'qwerty';

// attempt to check the attempted password against the server hashed pasword.
$pwVerify = $bcrypt->verify($serverPw, $passAttempt); 

if ( $pwVerify == 1 ) {echo "$pwVerify = true";} else {echo "$pwVerify = not true";}
// I also tried if ($pwVerify) and if ($bcrypt->verify($serverPw, $passAttempt))
// Output is "= not true"
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: No error, just "= not true" as the result of the conditional if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must store the password AND the salt used when you BCrypt, or you'll never get the same string.
This class seems pretty broken to me, don't use it. See [this example](https://gist.github.com/972386) and [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.crypt.php) to directly use PHP's crypt function.

Edit : You probably should use [PHPPass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/), seems like a well tested and referenced library.

Comment: I haven't looked deep enough into it to say that the class is broken, but the salt is supposedly concatenated into the hash, it's the first part after `$2a$15$...`.

Comment: Read [this](http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) also, great source of information and it recommands OpenWall implementation for PHP